# Full Join on two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do a full join on two SQL queries, below:

**1st Query:**

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 4 THEN 0 ELSE quantity*price END) AS TValue
    ,COUNT(*) AS CountAll
FROM table1
WHERE Date>=@StartDate AND Date<=@EndDate
GROUP BY ID
```

**2nd Query:**

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS New
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Amend
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cancel
FROM Table2
WHERE Date2 >=@StartDate AND Date2<= @EndDate
GROUP BY ID
```

**Result from query1**

```
ID   CountAll     TValue    
-------------------------
id1     24         1020      
id2     13         2030      
id3      4          120
```

**Result from query 2:**

```
ID     New     Amend     Cancel
--------------------------------
id1    12         4         6
id2     7         6         1
id4     2         1         2
```

Needed output:

```
ID     TValue     CountAll     New    Amend    Cancel   Total(countall+new+amend+cancel)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id1    1020          24        12       4         6        46
Id2    2030          13         7       6         1        27
id3     120           4         0       0         0         4
Id4       0           0         2       1         2         5
```

I'll post my current solution if requested, but it is pretty far from working.

I've been doing a bit of research and I think I need to either make a union to join the ID'S, or just do a Full Join. (Second day ever doing sql)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write something like below:

```
select decode (a.id, null, b.id, a.id) as ID, a.TValue, CountAll, b.new, b.Amend, b.cancel 
   from (SELECT ID ,SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 4 THEN 0 ELSE quantity*price END) 
         AS TValue ,COUNT(*) AS CountAll 
         FROM table1 
         WHERE Date>=@StartDate AND Date<=@EndDate GROUP BY ID
        ) a FULL OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT ID , SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
            AS New ,SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 6               
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Amend , 
            SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cancel
            FROM Table2 WHERE Date2 >=@StartDate AND Date2<= @EndDate GROUP BY ID
        ) b
     on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Hi Yogendra, I am unable to test this as there is a red squigly line under "where a.xref(+) = b.xref(+)".
"Incorrect syntax near ')' Hovertext = "Cannot find either column "a" or the user-defined function or aggregate "a.id", or the name is ambiguous." - Any ideas?

Comment: I updated the answer. Can you please try now? If still issues, give me a minute. I will share a working query.

Comment: Updated answer should be working. Please let me know, if you are having any issue.

Comment: Wow Awesome Job! Pretty much perfect, only a couple of things;
Firstly, in the ID column there are a couple of NULL's but the ID column must always be populated. Any suggestions on how to make sure that this is always full?

secondly, Another column for the total amount of (Countall+new+amend+cancel) is neeeded

thank you so much!

Comment: Please refer the update `select` statement(first line) in the answer.

Comment: Thank you! How Do I get around the error of a null ID column if there is no matching ID between a.id and b.id, e.g. there is a B.ID but not an A.ID, can I make an IF statement or something to use B.ID if there is no A.ID?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  ID ,
            SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 4 THEN 0 ELSE quantity*price END) AS TValue,
            COUNT(*) AS CountAll
    FROM    table1
    WHERE   Date>=@StartDate AND Date<=@EndDate
    GROUP BY ID
) a FULL JOIN
(
    SELECT  ID ,
            SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS New ,
            SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Amend ,
            SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cancel
    FROM Table2
    WHERE Date2 >=@StartDate AND Date2<= @EndDate 
    GROUP BY ID
) b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: Hi John, Thank you so much for your answer!

Your code works, however, there are 2 "ID" columns in the output table, and I'm trying to make it only 1... any ideas?

Comment: @user1736733 did it worked? Some columns shows `NULL` as it is because it doesn't have a match. If you want it to display zero instead of `NULL`, use `COALESCE`, example `SELECT... COALESCE(a.TValue,0) AS TValue`

Comment: Hey John, It does work yes, but there are 2 "ID" columns, and I need to combine these columns into just 1 ID column. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this...

```
select isnull (a.id,b.id) as ID, a.TValue, CountAll, b.new, b.Amend, b.cancel   
from (SELECT ID ,SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 4 THEN 0 ELSE quantity*price END) AS TValue ,COUNT(*) AS CountAll         
                FROM table1          
                WHERE Date>=@StartDate AND Date<=@EndDate GROUP BY ID         ) a 
                FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT ID , SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS New ,SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Amend , SUM(CASE WHEN reason = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cancel       
                FROM Table2 WHERE Date2 >=@StartDate AND Date2<= @EndDate GROUP BY ID         ) b  on a.id = b.id
```